# Rational function simplifying

Tags: calculus, polynomials, rational-functions

From the definition of rational function $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$
, where P(x) and q(x) are polynomials and q(x) ≠ 0

so for the function  $f(x) = \frac{x^{-2}+3 }{x-5}$  by the definition f(x) isnt rational since the numerator is not polynomial

but by multiplying both numerator and denominator by $x^{2}$ we get

$f(x) = \frac{3x^{2}+1 }{x^{3}-5x^{2}}$ which is  rational

and can we say that both functions are equal at every point?

Comment: They are both defined at all reals except $0$ and $5$, and they are equal wherever they are defined, so they are simply two descriptions of the same function.

Comment: so f(x) is a rational function

Comment: Yes, because in the representation as a quotient of polynomials the denominator is not the zero function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not equal at every point.  They are equal where they are both defined, on the intersection of their domains, which is all real numbers except $0$ and $5$.  (So they are not equal at $0$ or at $5$ since they aren't even defined there.)

Comment: thanks for the answer but the main question is f(x) rational or not?

Comment: @MohammedBadrieh : That question appears nowhere in the Question.  The only question in the Question is "can we say that both functions are equal at every point?"

Comment: @MohammedBadrieh : However, the answer to this additional question is "it depends delicately on your definition of rational function".  If we take the English Wikipedia's definition, "a rational function is any function which can be defined by a rational fraction", then this function is a rational function because it can be defined as a ratio of polynomials.  (This requires: without changing its domain or any of its values on that domain.)